# Android Preventing Double Click On A Layout with handher

Tags: java, android, double-click

There is a button layout that also has a progress bar inside. When the button is clicked, it pauses for a few seconds and enters the next activity.
To prevent double click i think i have to put these codes on **OnclickListener**

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
    return;
}
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

But i don't no where

**My onClickListener** method:

```
btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
                    return;
                }
                mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstPageMoneyTransfer.this, SecondPageMoneyTransfer.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }, 4500);

    }
});
```

I change my listener to :

```
btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                    return;
                }

                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstPageMoneyTransfer.this, SecondPageMoneyTransfer.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }, 4500);
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
});
```

But when I clicked on the button several times, it opened the next activity several times

Answer (score 2):

Please remove handler and put your logic code there e.g.

```
btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
                        return;
                    }            

                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstPageMoneyTransfer.this, SecondPageMoneyTransfer.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }, 4500);
          mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need that handler.

Comment: What can I do to pause for 4 seconds to go to the next activity?

Comment: then put this line out of handler
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

Comment: When I clicked on the button several times, it opened the next activity several times

Comment: what happen for several times? Please check logcat is there any erro or crash?.

Comment: No errors.But i should to press back several times to go to previous activity.

Comment: If you press back then activity instance destroy so this code will not work. If you stay in this activity for 4500 milli sec then this code will execute else not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218616/discussion-between-mohammad-and-vishal-sojitra).